# Пролагивания при прослушивания событий мыши при помощи pynput

Tags: python, pynput

Есть следующий код:

```
import keyboard
import time
import os
import subprocess
import threading
import mouse
from pynput import mouse as pynput_mouse


def run_program1():
    os.startfile(r'd:\Программы\1.jpg')


def run_program2():
    os.system('start "" "d:\\Программы\\2\\"')


def run_program3():
    subprocess.run(r'd:\Программы\3TCShell.exe')


def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    global wheel_scrolled
    wheel_scrolled = True


def main():
    try:
        global wheel_scrolled

        listener = pynput_mouse.Listener(on_scroll=on_scroll)
        listener.start()

        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('right ctrl'):
                wheel_scrolled = False
                pressed_keys = []
                clicked = False
                press_time = time.time()
                while keyboard.is_pressed('right ctrl'):
                    key = keyboard.read_key()
                    if key not in pressed_keys and key != 'right ctrl':
                        pressed_keys.append(key)
                    if mouse.is_pressed(button=mouse.LEFT) or mouse.is_pressed(button=mouse.MIDDLE) or mouse.is_pressed(button=mouse.RIGHT) or mouse.is_pressed(button=mouse.X) or mouse.is_pressed(button=mouse.X2):
                        clicked = True
                    time.sleep(0.13)
                release_time = time.time()
                duration = release_time - press_time
                if not pressed_keys and not clicked and not wheel_scrolled:
                    if 0.6 <= duration <= 1.5:
                        threading.Thread(target=run_program1).start()
                    elif 1.5 <= duration <= 2.5:
                        threading.Thread(target=run_program2).start()
                    elif 2.5 <= duration <= 4.5:
                        threading.Thread(target=run_program3).start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Программа завершена.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Он работает верно, но при зажатии правого Ctrl мышь начинает сильно лагать до закрытия программы. Как это исправить?